# Can't Instantiate Obj C Class in Swift in spite of working bridging header

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header

I'm working on pulling a single objective c class into swift. I've got my bridging header working just fine- Xcode is even suggesting the obj c class's name when I type it. I've even managed to reference a delegate protocol in the same header file from my swift file:

**BrowserViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class BrowserViewController: UIViewController, BrowserTabViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var browserView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var webViewContainer: UIView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tabview: BrowserTabView = BrowserTabView();
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

[Sreen cap of the error: Use of unresolved identifier 'BrowserTabView'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOpWr.png) Note that the `BrowserTabViewDelegate` isn't having any problems with being referenced. It comes from the same obj c header as the BrowserTabView. It suggests the class name, but I can't call init on it.

**BrowserTabView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class BrowserTabView;

@protocol BrowserTabViewDelegate <NSObject>

@optional

-(void)BrowserTabView:(BrowserTabView *)browserTabView didSelectTabAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
-(void)BrowserTabView:(BrowserTabView *)browserTabView willRemoveTabAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
-(void)BrowserTabView:(BrowserTabView *)browserTabView didRemoveTabAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
-(void)BrowserTabView:(BrowserTabView *)browserTabView exchangeTabAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index withTabAtIndex:(NSUInteger)toIndex;
-(BOOL)BrowserTabView:(BrowserTabView *)tabView shouldChangeTitle: (NSString*)title;

@end

@interface BrowserTabView : UIView <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *backgroundImage;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSUInteger numberOfTabs;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger selectedTabIndex;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSMutableArray *reuseQueue;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<BrowserTabViewDelegate> delegate;

-(id)initwithTabTitles:(NSArray *)titles andDelegate:(id)del;
-(void)addTabWithTitle:(NSString *)title;
-(void)setTabTitlesWithArray:(NSArray *)titles;
-(void)setSelectedTabIndex:(NSInteger)selectedTabIndex animated:(BOOL)animation;
-(void)removeTabAtIndex:(NSInteger)index animated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gr;
- (void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender;


@end
```

This is the first time I've been stuck for this long on an issue like this... Most of the existing questions I've seen have to do with bad bridging headers- but I'm pretty certain mine is good. Let me know if I can clean up my question, and thanks in advance for any help.

**WI Vision-Bridging-Header.h**

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
#import "BrowserTabView.h"
#import "BrowserTab.h"
```

Comment: sorry about the confusion. could you post the bridging header?

Comment: Done, bottom of question

Comment: does BrowserTab import BrowserTabView? are they related in any way?

Comment: They both import one another- but both are building without any issues as far as I can see.

Comment: that might be a problem cause you might have an import cycle that cannot be resolved. Are you only adding the import in the .m file?

Comment: That wasn't it. I just fixed the error by removing my reference to the BrowserTabViewDelegate in the third line of that first file... I have no idea why this worked, and I am hoping to have the protocol too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a nice issue. That looks like a bug and we can log it to Swift's  community. Changing the delegate following way will help you:

```
@protocol BrowserTabViewDelegate <NSObject>

@optional

-(void)browserTabView:(BrowserTabView *)browserTabView didSelectTabAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
-(void)browserTabView:(BrowserTabView *)browserTabView willRemoveTabAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
-(void)browserTabView:(BrowserTabView *)browserTabView didRemoveTabAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
-(void)browserTabView:(BrowserTabView *)browserTabView exchangeTabAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index withTabAtIndex:(NSUInteger)toIndex;
-(BOOL)browserTabView:(BrowserTabView *)tabView shouldChangeTitle: (NSString*)title;

@end
```

There should be **browserTabView** used instead of **BrowserTabView** in the methods names.

Comment: I have logged an issue. Let see what they replay: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1279

Comment: @Bengovernment Does it make sense? BTW, the issue has been resolved as duplicated. As I understand that's expected behaviour for a while. Similar  problem can be reproduced with pure Swift.

Comment: This is correct. Such a bizarre issue. Thanks for the help!